# SQL:How to group the dates from a certain date of each month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to group the sales date starting from a certain date. The date is determined by the date when the sales data is exported. In the example below is the data is exported on 2016/11/10.

Then the sales date should be grouped into the yellow column to calculate the sales during each period.

I tried the dateadd function, but since the each month might have different different days, so it doesn't work.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is the data always exported on the 10th?  If not, do you record the exported date in a table?

Comment: @ destination-data,no it is not always 10th. I might do it several times in a month.

Comment: How do you know what the date is?  Is it recorded in a table?  Or is it always the current day (ie if you export on the 24th then use the 24th)?

Comment: if you make a calendar table, with the periods defined in it, e.g. periodId,PeriodStartDate, PeriodEndDate - then you can join your data to the calendar table and group by periodid

Comment: can you provide the table structure?

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual, the table structure has been uploaded.

Comment: destination-data, the date is up to when I export the sales data from the system. I need to do some analysis based on these date group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this challenge is finding something you can group on.  As this doesn't exist in the data you will need to create it.  My basic idea is to offset the date.  Days that fall after the current day-of-month are pushed into the following month.  This gives us a reporting month, which we can group on.

My query uses the following sample data:

```
-- Generates a sample table.
-- Contains one record per day, between Dec 1st 2015 and Feb 29th 2016.
DECLARE @BaseDate DATE = '2015-12-01';
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        DateKey DATE
    )
;

WHILE @BaseDate < '2016-02-29'
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @Sample
        (
            DateKey
        )
    VALUES
        (@BaseDate)
    ;

    SET @BaseDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @BaseDate);
END
```

And here it is:

```
-- Offsets the date into reporting month groups.
SELECT
    DateKey,
    CASE        
        WHEN DAY(DateKey) > DAY(GETDATE())THEN 
            CASE MONTH(DateKey) WHEN 12 THEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DateKey) + 1, 1, 1)
            ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DateKey), MONTH(DateKey) + 1, 1)
        END             
        ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DateKey), MONTH(DateKey), 1)
    END AS ReportingMonth
FROM    
    @Sample
WHERE
    DateKey BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2016-04-30'
ORDER BY 
    DateKey DESC
;
```

If you run this on the 24th of a month the results look like:

```
DateKey     ReportingMonth
2016-02-28  2016-03-01
2016-02-28  2016-03-01
2016-02-27  2016-03-01
2016-02-26  2016-03-01
2016-02-25  2016-03-01
2016-02-24  2016-02-01    -- Reporting period changes here.
2016-02-23  2016-02-01
2016-02-22  2016-02-01
...
2015-12-03  2015-12-01
2015-12-02  2015-12-01
2015-12-01  2015-12-01
```

To be honest I'm not happy with this query.  I'm sure it could be improved and simplified.  But hopefully, it provides you with a good starting point.